# Dynamically rename/map columns according to Azure Table data model convention

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

How would you dynamically rename/map columns according to Azure Table data model convention, property key name should follow C# identifiers. Since we cannot guarantee the columns coming to us conform to the standard, or when we get new columns in, that it is automatically fixed.

Example:

```
column_1 (something_in_parens), column with spaces, ...
returned...
column_1 something_in_parens, column_with_spaces, ...
```

The obvious solution might be to run a databricks python step in front of the Copy Data functionality, but maybe Copy Data is able to inflect the right schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
columns = ["some Not so nice column Names", "Another ONE", "Last_one"]
​
new_columns = [x.lower().replace(" ", "_") for x in columns]

# returns ['some_not_so_nice_column_names', 'another_one', 'last_one']
```